# xTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! Cell : unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift

**Considering this code**

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var cellLabel: UILabel!
}
```

**EDIT: Nothing in the viewDidLoad method for the moment.**

I'm trying to put text in cellLabel in this other ViewController in cellForRowAt:indexPath method

```
let cellText = listTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! Cell
cellText.cellLabel.text = array[indexPath.section].datas[indexPath.row].name // ERROR HERE
```

When I run the app I have the following error message on the second line

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Let me know what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks :)

Comment: You probably didn't register your cell, but there isn't enough information here to actually provide an answer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Register my cell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your "number of rows" method returns array[indexPath.section]. datas .count ?

If it's not the problem come from here because if you put something like

"number of rows in section = 10" but there is a section in your data source only containing 5 elements it will fail

Comment: The problem is not here, tableView gestion is correct, when I remove the two lines, it works perfectly. I just want to add a Label to print more informations in Cell.

Comment: When the app crash enter : "po array[indexPath.section].datas[indexPath.row].name" (in the debug console) to see the result

Comment: thats correct dude, the problem is not in my array. The problem come from the Cell class.

Comment: I can't find from where it comes, if you're sure the datasource is 100% correct it should work... 

just a little tip : 
instead of using `let cellText = listTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! Cell`
 that use a forceCast , you should use something like : 
`guard let cellText = listTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? Cell else { return UITableViewCell() } `

Comment: That works now, but it's printing nothing into the Label.

Comment: As Josh said , it seems your cell isnt registred , go in the storyboard , click on the cell you have and watch that in the attribute inspector in the field "Class " you have "Cell" (<- the name of your cell's class)

Comment: Ok the last thing I can say to (maybe) help you is that in the method "cell for row at indexpath..." 
I've always seen this : 

` let myCell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier : "myCellIdentifier", for indexPath) as! MyCellClass ` 

in your case, you should set an Identifier (in the attribute inspector) and it should be like that now that you use the "guard" statement that I gave you : 

`guard let cellText = listTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier : [the identifier you'veput],for indexPath) as? Cell else { return UITableViewCell() }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152648/discussion-between-pierreafranck-and-leo).